# PHP MySQL hierarchy data optimization

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, hierarchical-data

I have a table employees, which contains columns : **employee_id**, **name**, **employee_manager_id**.
**employee_manager_id** references to **employee_id**. It's a hierarchal data.

I have this output using PHP but couldn't achieve it using only one mySQL query. As of now, I need to process the data in PHP using recursive function so i can achieve this kind output.

```
Sample Array Output 
0 => (
                employee_id => 2,
                name => Jerald,
                employee_manager_id => 1,
                depth => 1
            ),
        1 => (
                employee_id => 3,
                name => Mark,
                employee_manager_id => 2,
                depth => 2
            ), 
        2 => (
                employee_id => 6,
                name => Cyrus,
                employee_manager_id => 3,
                depth => 3
            ), 
        3 => (
                employee_id => 4,
                name => Gerby,
                employee_manager_id => 2,
                depth => 2
            )
```

As of now, this is my recursive function in PHP to achieve the output above.

```
function get_employees_by_hierarchy( $_employee_id = 0, $_depth = 0, $_org_array = array() ) {
    if ( $this->org_depth < $_depth ) {
        $this->org_depth = $_depth;
    }

    $_depth++;
    $_query = "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE ";

    if ( !$_employee_id ) {
        $_query .= "employee_manager_id IS NULL OR employee_manager_id = 0";
    }
    else { 
        $_query .= "employee_manager_id = " . $this->dbh->quoteSmart( $_employee_id );
    }
    $_result = $this->query( $_query );

    while ( $_row = $_result->fetchRow() ) {
        $_row['depth'] = $_depth;
        array_push( $_org_array, $_row );
        $_org_array = $this->get_employees_by_hierarchy(
            $_row['employee_id'],
            $_depth,
            $_org_array
        );
    }
    return $_org_array;
}
```

My question is, is there anyway so I can achieve the array output i want using just one mysql query?
If not possible in mysql query, is there anymore to optimize in my current code?

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I could write up a nice answer for this, but there are a number of blog articles covering this issue pretty thoroughly already.  Take a look at http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/ for one of the more common options

Answer (score 0):

You can try a nested set a.k.a. celko tree but insert and delete is very expensive. There is also closures and path enumeration (materialized path) but I'm not an expert. MySql doesn't support recursive queries.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get the depth with your current model without doing any processing on the results, but you don't need to make multiple queries.

Assuming `$employees` is the list of employees indexed by `employee_id`, you could do something like this:

```
function set_employee_depth(&$employees, $id) {
    if (!isset($employees[$id]['depth'])) {
        $employee_manager_id = (int) $employees[$id]['employee_manager_id'];
        if (!$employee_manager_id) {
            $employees[$id]['depth'] = 0;
        } elseif ($employee_manager_id !== $id) {
            $employees[$id]['depth'] = 1 + set_employee_depth($employees, $employee_manager_id);
        } else {
            throw new \Exception('Employee cannot be its own manager!');
        }
    }
    return $employees[$id]['depth'];
}

foreach ($employees as $id => $employee) {
    set_employee_depth($employees, $id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, your table is composed of 3 columns (`employee_id`, `name`, `employee_manager_id`). `employee_manager_id` is a self reference to `employee_id`. You want to construct an array with all records, adding an extra field called `depth` which represents the distance of said employee to the "big boss", with only one query to the database. Is that correct? I'm also assuming that the database structure can't be changed.

If these assumptions are correct, this is a basic **HIERARCHICAL/TREE** data structure and thus, you have a couple of ways you can tackle this problem.

---

## First Script

The first script runs the results array sequentially, finding the *main node / trunk* (the big boss) first and then adding it's children, then it's grandchildren and so on. Each time a node is "sorted", it will be removed from the cycle until no nodes are left. It assumes that:

- There are no Orphan records (employees with invalid managers_ids)
- There are no Circular References, either simple (*A is manager of B and B is manager of A*) or complex (*A manager of B, B manager of C and C manager of A)
- Each path (from the main node to last node) can have an infinite number of nodes
- `$results` are produced by running a simple query `SELECT * FROM employees ORDER BY employee_manager_id`

Code:

```
$finalArray = array();
$limit = count($results);

while (count($results) > 0) {
    $results[0]['cnt'] = isset($results[0]['cnt']) ? $results[0]['cnt']++ : 0; // set num of times each element was already visited
    if ($results[0]['cnt'] === $limit) { //prevent an infinite cycle
        break;
    }
    $manId = $results[0]['manager_id'];
    if ($manId === null) {
        $results[0]['depth'] = 0;
    } else if ( ($key = searchForId($manId, $finalArray)) !== null ) {
        $results[0]['depth'] = $finalArray[$key]['depth'] + 1; //use the depth of parent to calculate its own
    } else {
        $results[] = $results[0]; //parent was not visited yet so we add it to the end of array
        array_shift($results);
        continue;
    }
    unset($results[0]['cnt']);
    $finalArray[] = array_shift($results);   
}

function searchForId($id, $array) {
   foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
       if ($val['id'] === $id) {
           return $key;
       }
   }
   return null;
}
```

This script is pretty straightforward. It only runs one query to the DB. In best case scenario, it will only traverse the array once. **In worse case scenario, it will visit *each* element `count(array) - 1`, which can be slow with big arrays.** However, since the results are pre-sorted, best case scenario will probably be more common.

---

## Second Script

The second script builds an actual tree of elements. It's a bit more complex but achieves similar results. Also, the Depth is calculated dynamically.

```
class Employee {
    public $id;
    public $name;
    public $manager;
    
    public function __construct($id, $name, Employee $manager = null) {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->manager = $manager;
    }
    
    public function setManager(Employee $manager) {
        $this->manager = $manager;
    }
    
    public function getDepth() {
        if ($this->manager === null) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return $this->manager->getDepth() + 1;
        }
    }
}

$finalArray = array();
$paths = array();


foreach ($results as $r) {
    $finalArray[(int) $r['id']] = new Employee((int)$r['id'], $r['name']);
    if ($r['manager_id'] !== null) {
        $paths[(int) $r['id']] = (int) $r['manager_id'];
    }
}

foreach ($paths as $k => $v) {
    if (isset($finalArray[$k]) && isset($finalArray[$v])) {
        $finalArray[$k]->setManager($finalArray[$v]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a link for answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38264072/how-to-make-employee-hierarchy-tree-using-php?noredirect=1#comment63947766_38264072)

Here is full code for making tree structure for hierarchy management using php and mysql.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Although this may provide an answer to the question, link-only answers are discouraged because the link may become unavailable in the future. Please consider adding a little summary. Thank you.